# rollup: commonjs-proxy issued a warning: 'default' is not exported by 'node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rollup

```
[18:32:31]  rollup:
            commonjs-proxy:/Users/user/devel/saveup-mobile-front/node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js has
            issued a warning: 'default' is not exported by 'node_modules/@angular/http/@angular/http.es5.js'
[18:32:31]  rollup:
            commonjs-proxy:/Users/user/devel/saveup-mobile-front/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js has
            issued a warning: 'default' is not exported by 'node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js'
[18:32:31]  rollup: /Users/user/devel/saveup-mobile-front/node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/extension.js has
            issued a warning: Use of eval is strongly discouraged, as it poses security risks and may cause issues with
            minification
```

In our Ionic 3 Project we are seeing above warning when building. How to get rid?

Comment: i have same problems, do you have any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no solution. Ionic Team says this is the way it is.